# Sharepoint designer: Display custom field in a list

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

Hi I have a list named "Discussions List", I have created a custom column in that list. How can I display that field in a page??

Im working in SharePoint 2013 Community site. I have to display the custom field in Topic.aspx page through Sharepoint designer(xslt).

Comment: no i couldn't find any solution for this..

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data view web part in Sharepoint designer to display any list custom column on a page.
Google "data view web part" to find examples.